# Can neutrals be landed in an old panel which acts as a junction box?

Tags: electrical-panel, code-compliance, neutral, common-wire

I have a metered panel which had been stripped down and wires jumped over to new panel. The feed is still here but also jumped over. Can I land my neutrals from the new panel inside of the old main panel where the meter is?

I am asking because the neutrals are sized incorrectly on the jump. So the house it has number 10 AWG wire but they jumped over with number 12 AWG wire and it’s a rat's nest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming the buss bars in that CSED are still live?  That panel gives me the jeebies.

Answer (score 6):

Current flows in loops.  It's not like air tools where air only has to go one way.  Electric current has to come back too in a full loop.

Neutral is the return path that carries 100% of the current - the same amount of current as the hot.

Ground does not handle any current at all except during fault conditions (which aren't supposed to last long).

### Neutrals must go all the way individually!

So -- neutrals have to go all the way back to the actual panel containing the circuit breaker.

So think same as the hot. You wouldn't land 10 hots in the old panel and feed them from one breaker, would you? Obviously not, it would overload (and trip the breaker!)  Well the same exact thing would happen with neutral, **except neutrals don't have breakers*** so it would just catch on fire.

It is absolutely essential that the hot-neutral *pairs* (or triplets for MWBCs) be clearly identified and marked so that the next guy working in the panel knows **which** neutral is with **which** hot wire(s). That is a Code requirement.  *I'm not a big fan of those numbered wire marking tapes that I see, because I have panels with a bunch of curled up number marking tapes in the bottom of the panel, and a bunch of unidentified wires with dried up residue from that tape*.

A better plan is to sleeve the pairs/triplets with shrink tube.  It's not super essential that you be able to tell one pair from another - that is easy to do via testing.  But which hot goes with which neutral must be identified at all points where there could possibly be confusion.

### Grounds, though

Grounds are a different deal. They don't need to go individually back to the panel. They can be combined in an earlier junction box, and carried as 1 ground wire of the largest size.

Further, anytime you have metal conduit that isn't flexible, that metal conduit *is itself* a valid ground path.  Which means that 1 ground wire can be no ground *wires* at all.   The ground wires can simply be terminated by grounding to the first box (in the metal conduit network) that they reach.  If that's the original panel, just land them on the original panel's ground bus and you're done. "That was easy!"

If you want to buy an "accessory ground bar" and attach it to a steel gutter or enclosure and land a bunch of grounds there, that is fine as long as the mounting screws are machine screws (NOT sheetmetal screws) and are #8-32 or 10-32.   (-32 minimum thread pitch, 10-24 not allowed!)

It's obvious that whoever wired your panel *didn't get the memo on that*, and painstakingly wired and identified dozens of grounds in pipes that are metal.    What a lot of work for nothing, and a royal mess to boot.  I would question that person's qualifications, they really have no business working in THHN/EMT installations.

SMH I can't believe that guy wasted $50 on a spool of green wire.  99% of my work is in EMT conduit, and I own 10 colors of wire, and I don't own any green LOL.

### The panel review you didn't ask for

It looks to me like that main bus is still energized and that costly HOM2200 breaker there is feeding to the new panel.  **The panel deadfront cover needs to be put back on** NEC 110.3. **There need to be approved blanking plates over all openings** NEC 408.7.  From how the wires lay, it looks to me like the deadfront has been tossed and only the outer door is being used.

The panel looks newer, and a Square D dealer may be able to get you a new deadfront with all twist-outs intact. Then you can twist out the 4 needed for the HOM2200 breaker there.  Otherwise buy a couple dozen HOMFPCP filler plates, or better, ask your AHJ if it's OK to use pop-rivets to attach sheets of appropriate thickness steel. They can approve such field modifications to enclosures.

Judging by the dust in the new panel, it looks like more twist-outs are missing there, or the person just isn't using the deadfront at all.  Again you can buy a new deadfront with twist-outs intact, or use blank cover plates, **or honestly, I prefer actual breakers instead of blanks** - they are like $6 instead of $4, do a much better job (are more sturdy) and you can use them for future projects, what's not to like?

I see a wire in the new panel that is black with white tape.  Check the wire size - that is only allowed if the wire is #4 or larger (#3, #2, #1/0, #4/0 etc.)  If it is #6 or smaller it must be natively white or gray, or green if ground.

Comment: I always like to use leftover NM jacket for my pair-markers.  Bonus points for the future owners if you use the right colors because 14 and 12 are a little hard to tell apart just by sight once the jacket is gone.

If someone really likes to label the cables individually, I've found that any labels that purport to stick to the insulation are garbage and will end up lying in curls at the bottom of the panel as you said.  I have, however, found label tape specifically for IDing cables that sticks to itself and I still have some of those intact after a decade of sitting behind a server exhaust.

Comment: @ChrisO Also, when doing extensions like this, smart play is to buy black and white #12 THHN, and that means 15A circuits arrive in the new panel on #12 wire.